# How to disable Intel turbo boost on my Dell laptop with i5 processor?

Tags: turbo-boost

I want to disable the Intel turbo boost on my Dell i5 laptop. Even for regular activity like starting the chrome or IE, turbo boost is starting and especially I am annoyed by the heat and fan noise it makes while it is starts turbo boost. Please help me out as it more nuisance rather than the performace boost.

Comment: You should be able to do this while within BIOS.  If there isn't an option this is one of those features that cannot be disabled from within an operating system.

Comment: If possible can I have any link so that I can disable it

Comment: I don't have a link and the exact instructions would be specific to the motherboard.  Have you simply tried booting into your BIOS and looking for the option to disable it?  If your asking me to prove this is the solution I wouldn't do that even if there was a link.

Comment: Chances are good that even if "turbo boost" itself did not engage, the heat and the fans ramping up would still occur when the cpu (and/or gpu) goes to work.   I would much rather have a laptop that the fans work a bit too hard, than to have a laptop that is overheating :-)

Comment: On Linux, it is possible to disable Intel Turbo Boost by using a tool like `cpufrequtils` and limiting the frequency to the minimum available. For example on my CPU with 2 cores and 4 threads, I saw that the minimum is 800 MHz with the command `cpufreq-info`. In my case, here is the command to limit frequency to 800 MHz for all threads: `sudo sh -c "cpufreq-set -c 0 -u 800MHz; cpufreq-set -c 1 -u 800MHz; cpufreq-set -c 2 -u 800MHz; cpufreq-set -c 3 -u 800MHz"`.
The fan / heating problem may also come from useless processes on startup, drivers not up-to-date or dust in your computer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, it’s relatively easy.

Go to **Control Panel** -> **Hardware and Sound** -> **Power Options** and click **Change plan settings** near your plan (e.g. I use *High performance* for CPU intensive tasks, such as gaming).

Then click on **Change advanced power settings**.

Scroll down to **Processor power management** and expand it.

Expand **Maximum processor state** and modify both On battery and Plugged in to **99%**.

Then simply click Apply and OK.

Note:

Also please make sure, that Minimum processor state is not greater than Maximum processor state (in this case - 99%), because it won't wprk. I suggest you to set it to 5% or so.

And that’s it, no more Turbo Boost, no more overheating and if there is a need - these changes are very easy to revert. What you just did is created a limit, that prevents your laptop to go into such state, when Turbo Boost kicks in.

Comment: Setting it to 99 % doesn't seem to disable Turbo Boost completely for me, 90 % does seem to work.

Comment: i noticed that for some reason my Minimum processor state was at 100% causing turbo boost to bounce up and down crazy so i reset plan and everything seems ok now