# Can I overclock my Intel I7 CPU?

Tags: cpu, overclocking

My notebook specs:

```
HP DV6-6177EE
Core I7 2630QM
HD 6770M swicthable graphics
8GB DDR3 1333Mhz
```

Can do I overclock that Intel CPU? What software to use?
I've searched but no results.

It's actually weird that the GPU is overclockable while the CPU is not.

Comment: May I ask you why you need to over clock an i7 processor? I down clocked my because of heat and still playing all new games in ultra resolution.

Comment: If you feel your notebook is too cool, you could also introduce additional heat with a Bunsen burner (or similar).

Answer (score 4):

This is not necessary, your processor has the Turbo Boost technology:

> Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.0 automatically allows processor
>   cores to run faster than the rated operating frequency if they’re
>   operating below power, current, and temperature specification limits.

[More information on Intel web site](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html?wapkw=intel%20turbo%20boost)

[Your processor datasheet](http://ark.intel.com/fr/products/52219/Intel-Core-i7-2630QM-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-2_90-GHz)

Comment: Yeah, and that was pretty silly in my case. As I played a games with a lot of floating point operations, turbo goes on and brings the temperature to 100 degree with 23 % overheat. So my PC just turns off every time.

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful for you to disable it in Windows 7:

http://superuser.com/questions/627665/how-to-disable-intel-turbo-boost-on-my-dell-laptop-with-i5-processor