# Persistently disable Power Level 2 (PL2) of an Intel CPU

Tags: linux, cpu, power-supply, cpu-throttling

I would like to permanently/persistently disable the PL2 power level of an Intel CPU in a laptop. Is it possible? How?

Some explanations: [*Why Intel Processors Draw More Power Than Expected: TDP and Turbo Explained*](https://www.anandtech.com/show/13544/why-intel-processors-draw-more-power-than-expected-tdp-turbo).

In case it matters, my CPU is [Intel Pentium Silver N5030](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/197308/intel-pentium-silver-n5030-processor-4m-cache-up-to-3-10-ghz.html), and I am using Linux.

---

*Update.* As suggested in a comment, i tried to look for "Disable Intel turbo boost on Linux" instead, and found some solutions here: [*Disabling Intel Turbo Boost in ubuntu*](https://askubuntu.com/q/619875). Those solutions however require scripting or "manually" manipulating MSR registers, which i am somewhat uncomfortable with. I didn't find a switch in the BIOS of my laptop.

Comment: The page you linked suggests that PL2 is linked to turbo boost. Is disabling turbo boost an option for you?

Comment: [How to disable Intel turbo boost on my Dell laptop with i5 processor?](https://superuser.com/questions/627665/how-to-disable-intel-turbo-boost-on-my-dell-laptop-with-i5-processor)

Comment: @Mokubai, indeed, i suppose this must have the same effect.

Comment: I just realised that the duplicate is for Windows. In theory you should also be able to disable Turbo from your BIOS menu, it is often in there under CPU options.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling turbo boost on Linux, if it's using the
intel_pstate frequency scaling driver, is done by the command:

```
echo "1" | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/no_turbo
```

To check if intel_pstate frequency scaling is being used, run:

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver
```

---

If intel_pstate frequency scaling is not used,
you need to install the msr-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install msr-tools
```

To disable do this :

```
wrmsr -a 0x1a0 0x4000850089
```

For more information, see the post
[Disabling Intel Turbo Boost in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/619875/disabling-intel-turbo-boost-in-ubuntu).